# How do I merge categories for crosstab in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose my pandas dataframe has 3 categories for variable `X`: `[A, B, C]` and 2 categories for variable `Y`:`[D,E]`. I want to cross-tab this, with something like:

```
+--------+----------------------+-----+
|  X/Y   |          D           |  E  |
+--------+----------------------+-----+
| A or B | count(X=A or B, Y=D) | ... |
| C      | count(X=C),Y=D)      | ... |
+--------+----------------------+-----+
```

Comment: Did you have a look at pandas.crosstab (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], size=10)
y = np.random.choice(['D', 'E'], size=10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':x, 'Y':y})
df.head()
```

Output:

```
    X   Y
0   A   D
1   B   D
2   B   E
3   B   D
4   A   E
```

Dataframe modifications:

```
df['X'] = df['X'].apply(lambda x: 'A or B' if x == 'A' or x == 'B' else x)
```

Crosstab application:

```
pd.crosstab(df.X, df.Y)
```

Output:

```
Y       D   E
X       
A or B  1   3
C       4   2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.pivot_table()` for this purpose. This should do the trick - `df` refers to input dataframe.

```py
import numpy as np

df["catX"]=np.where(df["X"].isin(["A","B"]), "AB", np.where(df["X"]=="C", "C", "other"))

df2=df.pivot_table(index="catX", columns="Y", aggfunc='count', values="X")
```

Sample output:

```py
#input - df with extra categorical column - catX
    X  Y catX
0   A  D   AB
1   B  D   AB
2   C  E    C
3   B  E   AB
4   C  D    C
5   B  D   AB
6   C  D    C
7   A  E   AB
8   A  D   AB
9   A  E   AB
10  C  E    C
11  C  E    C
12  A  E   AB

#result:
Y     D  E
catX
AB    4  4
C     2  3
```