# How do I merge categories for crosstab in pandas where some categories are common?

Tags: python, pandas

[A while ago I asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431633/how-do-i-merge-categories-for-crosstab-in-pandas/59431990#59431990)

But that does not cover the case where two merged categories might have a common category

In that case I wanted to merge the categories A and B into AB. What if I have categories A, B, C and I want to merge A,B into AB, and B,C into BC?

Suppose I have the data:

```
+---+---+
| X | Y |
+---+---+
| A | D |
| B | D |
| B | E |
| B | D |
| A | E |
| C | D |
| C | E |
| B | E |
+---+---+
```

I want the cross-tab to look like:

```
+--------+---+---+
|  X/Y   | D | E |
+--------+---+---+
| A or B | 3 | 3 |
| B or C | 3 | 2 |
| C      | 1 | 1 |
+--------+---+---+
```

Comment: what should be output if you have `A,B,C and D` ?

Comment: @anky_91 I don't completely understand what you mean

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) by all unique values and then sum values by selecting by categories in index values:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.X, df.Y)
df.loc['A or B'] = df.loc[['A','B']].sum()
df.loc['B or C'] = df.loc[['C','B']].sum()
df = df.drop(['A','B'])
print (df)
Y       D  E
X           
C       1  1
A or B  3  3
B or C  3  3
```

EDIT: If want general solution it is not easy, because is necessary repeat groups with `rename` like:

```
df1 = df[df['X'] == 'B'].assign(X = 'B or C')
df2 = df[df['X'] == 'C']
df = pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True)
df['X'] = df['X'].replace({'A':'A or B', 'B': 'A or B', 'C': 'B or C'})
df = pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index=True)

df = pd.crosstab(df.X, df.Y)
print (df)
Y       D  E
X           
A or B  3  3
B or C  3  3
C       1  1
```

Comment: What if I don't just want count, but have a target variable and aggregate functions?

Comment: @RwitabanGoswami - Possible, but not very general solution, answer was edited.